# EVERYTHING is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file IF ".EXE" SUFFIX IS MISSING

Tags: command-line, path, environment-variables, windows-7-x64

this problem might not be the problem as u may expect and I'm using Windows 7. I've guaranteed that I have put the path to EVERY SINGLE EXECUTABLE FILE I need in the %PATH%.
Yet I still can't run them nice and smooth by simply type there file name.

For instance, I've already setup my python correctly, now I open my cmd in a totally irrelevant directory, says U:\\

**U:\>python**

'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

**U:\>python.exe**

Python 3.7.5 on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

And also, 'ipconfig' has the completely same issue as above:

**U:\>ipconfig**

'ipconfig' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

**U:\>ipconfig.exe**

Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection: .......

What!!! How come I MUST type the extension ".exe" to make this happen? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What does `set pathext` say?

Comment: @Stephan It says “ PATHEXT=.PY;.PYW”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something messed up the `PATHEXT` variable on your system. This variable tells windows how to handle files with certain extensions. Or in other words, if you try to execute a file (without extension), Windows takes that variable to try to execute it with the extensions therein (in that order - so if there is a `file.bat`  and another one `file.exe` and you execute just `file`, Windows looks into `PATHEXT` and then executes `file.exe`, because `.EXE` is listed before `.BAT` (short form - actually, also the `PATH` variable is involved).

On a fresh Win10, `PATHEXT` has the following content:

```
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

Note, the content of `PATHEXT` depends on what was installed on your Windows (in your case, it's supposed to be at least:

```
.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW
```

(maybe more - as I said, it depends on your configuration)

Answer (score -1):

typing "start" before the program name.
If this does not work, try using the "cd" command to mount itself at the place of the program you would like to run